как исправить ошибку 'int' object is not iterable
def dven(n):
   c = 0
   b = 0
   n = str(n)
   for i in len(n[::-1]):
      b += int(n[i]) * (12**c)
      c += 1
   return b

print(dven(144))

Это код для перевода из 10 системы счисления в 12.
Почему выводит ошибку, хотя на 4 строке есть перевод в строку

Вот здесь for i in <Iterable> должен быть итерируемый объект, а len() возвращает int, отсюда и ошибка.

Вы перебираете длину строки, а не саму строку

^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/emin/.vscode/Emoon.py", line 6, in dven
b+=int(n[i])*(12**c)
~^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
Как исправить?

Что тут исправлять - абсолютно всё неверно, прямо-таки дичь... Начните с учебника по языку. for i in range(len... снимет ошибку, но проблема не решится.

хаха реально дичь написана

В учебных целях подойдёт что-нибудь такое:
def dven(n):
    digits = '0123456789AB'
    result = ''
    while True:
        result = digits[n % 12] + result
        n //= 12
        if n == 0:
            break
    return result

print(dven(7354))

>>> 430A


А почему нельзя написать

result = Digits[n % 12] + result - не питонично это :/  Во-первых с большой буквы должны называться классы, а переменные с маленькой. Во-вторых не нужно конкатенировать строки, это харам, добавляйте просто в список, а в конце объедините с переворотом return ''.join(reversed(result)). Вроде и мелочи, но не нужно учить плохим практикам. )  Хотя второе возможно сложновато для начинающих...

@CrazyElf В данном случае автору хорошо бы понять саму последовательность действий, а со списком это немного теряется.

В данном случае не буду настаивать )
